# How to override TIniFile.Create?

Tags: delphi

How to override TIniFile.Create constructor ?

This code is not working because Create is static:

```
  TMyIniFile = class(TIniFile)
   protected
   public
     constructor Create  (CONST AppName: string); override;  <------ Error 'Cannot override a non-virtual method' 
   end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot override the constructor of `TIniFile` since it is not virtual. The ini file classes do not use virtual constructors.

You simply need to remove the `override` from your code.

```
TMyIniFile = class(TIniFile)
public
  constructor Create(const AppName: string);
end;
```

Implement it like this:

```
constructor TMyIniFile.Create(const AppName: string);
begin
  inherited Create(FileName);//I can't tell what you need as FileName
  FAppName := AppName;
end;
```

When you need to create one you do so like this:

```
MyIniFile := TMyIniFile.Create(MyAppName);
```

Comment: This is exactly what `TMemIniFile` does.